# Apple ID's -- I have apple id's on two devices

Tags: itunes, icloud, ios-appstore, apple-id

I have the same apple id on two devices can i delete one app on one device without deleting it on the other device. There are lots of apps which I would like to have and lots of apps which I wouldn't like to have. Also like games with levels etc. do you start from THAT level or from the beginning? E.G simsfreeplay I use icloud to back up this game can I download it on another device (same app) but with the same id?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can absolutely have multiple devices using the same Apple ID and have different apps and the same apps installed on them. What apps are installed on each device is managed by the individual device and/or by iTunes when you sync.

There are not many games or apps that allow for sync'ng across multiple devices though, so for most apps the content will be unique to each device. Hopefully the developers will catch on that many of us are using their apps on iPhones and iPads and get them to sync.